# Going to the previous page

Tags: jquery

I have the following piece of code:

```
$j('#flagUpdateID').click(function() {
    var form = $j('#messageUpdateForm');
    post = $j.post(
        '/myapp/form/ajaxUpdateMessageWithFlags', 
        form.serialize(), 
        function(data) {
            $j().message("Message Updated With Flags", function() {
            })
        }
    );
});
```

I have tried adding `history.back(-1)` before and after the `.message` call but it doesn't seem to take me to the previous page. How can I get to the previous page after an AJAX call?

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like [jquery Address](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/) to provide reliable redirection from an ajax call.